# In end-to-end encryption, Does private key of A is similar to private key of B

Tags: encryption

I reading about end-to-end encryption and I wonder in situation that

If A will send message to B, he use public key from B to encrypt, Then message will send and decrypted by B with private key. I name this key is "Kab"

And if B will send message to A, Dose he use "Kab" key or use another key?

Comment: Data (messages) are generally encrypted with a symmetric key algorithm that both ends share in some manner. Note that the data size for asymmetric key algorithm must be less than the key size which is a substantial limitation. An asymmetric key algorithm can be used to establish a shared symmetric key as can Diffie–Hellman key exchange.

Comment: The whole point of public key is, you can _publish_ your  public key---tell everybody in the world, and everybody can send you messages, but only you can read them.

Comment: Normally, you don't use public key to send the message itself:  You encrypt the message using a one-time-only, randomly generated _session key_, and then you use the other guy's public key to encrypt the session key, and send him both encrypted things.  The reason is, if you encrypt more than one message with the same key, and the messages contain anything that's guessable, then the bad guys can use that information to break the key.  So, you encrypt your guessable text with a one-time-only key, and you use your public key only to encrypt unguessable, randomly generated session keys.

Comment: @jameslarge In general, knowing the encrypted message, even many with the same key, can not expose the key. This would be a chosen text attack and would fail for any good cipher algorithm. What is potentially exposed is some meaning between the message such as "yes" or "no". Using a random IV guards against this when using the same key for multiple messages. What using the same key does is if the key is found for one message all other messages with the same key can be decrypted. Thus TLS perfect forward secrecy uses one-time keys to avoid past messages being decrypted by an exposed key.

Comment: This question is not about development and is therefore off topic here. You could ask on the crypto.SE site, but as this is basic cryptography that can be found in any entry level book it's not likely to receive too much attention or upvotes there either.

Answer (score 1):

If you want secure asymmetric encryption, B would encrypt a message using A's public key.  If B uses their private key to encrypt the message, *anyone* with B's public key could decrypt it - not very secure!

More generally, there are lots of useful resources concerning encryption out there - starting from the wikipedia page would probably be a good idea: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography